# Is there a way to enable click and drag for a plotLine on a highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple line chart rendered with highcharts that displays some datapoints (y axis) over time (x axis). I have a vertical plotLine on the chart rendered using highchart's xAxis plotLine feature.

I would like to allow my users to click and drag this plotLine to the left or right. Is there a way to do that?

My overall goal is to use this plotLine and an additional one to allow the user to select a date range (because my xAxis is dates) that I then use elsewhere in my application.

Comment: Why not use the master/detail chart capability or use HighStock's navigator?

Comment: I decided to use the highcharts zoom feature. (zoomType:'x'). Works nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of plotLine, you can add line by `Renderer()` and then add drag&drop in the way, introduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/ASvWB/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

Comment: The link to the `Renderer()` api for Highcharts takes us to a 404.. I think it was moved to:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer